# Google Analytics Search Metrics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to implement google analytics search metrics. I have a ecommerce site. My requirement is that when i search for categories a list of products appears. Every product has like/ unlike button.

I need to track number of likes per search in google analytics.

Is this doable by google analytics ?

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

> Events are user interactions with content that can be tracked
>   independently from a web page or a screen load. Downloads, mobile ad
>   clicks, gadgets, Flash elements, AJAX embedded elements, and video
>   plays are all examples of actions you might want to track as Events.

To fulfil your requirement, you could implement the event tracking as follows:

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);

// you may add this implementation, says when someone like a product:
ga('send', 'event', 'Products', 'like', 'Search Page');

// or when someone unlike a product
ga('send', 'event', 'Products', 'dislike', 'Search Page');
```

If you have unique URL and PageView Tracking for each search, you have done and can view the metrics on `Events > Top Events`, with second dimension `Page`, filtered by search page.

Otherwise, you should setup [Site Search](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en#Params). Send the pageview tracking manually as follows:

```
analytics.js: ga('send', 'pageview', '/search_results.php?q=keyword');
```

Comment: if i use analytics.js: ga('send', 'pageview', '/search_results.php?q=keyword');  this will store the url but on this url there are lets say 50 products and i can like and unlike it. How i can count the like values which i have done for individual search!

Comment: you should combine with event tracking. you could set the primary dimension is `eventAction` and second dimension is `page`, then you can check how many total events `like` & `dislike` for each `page`. and you could add some filter limit to include `eventLabel` to `Search Page`.